# How do I instantiate a char datatype in Java?

Tags: java, primitive-types

Input:

```
1
1.2
A
```

If line1 is integer then I return

```
new Integer(1);
```

If line2 is float then I return

```
new Float(1.2);
```

What should return for line 3 being a character?

Comment: new Character('A');

Comment: what if it has a string "A"? @MichaelMarkidis

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: Why do you need objects instead of primitives?

Comment: What if it has a long? What if it has a byte? What if has a null? What if it has a short? What if it has double? What if it has a ?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I meant the line is read as a String and so my code wasn't working with new Character(<String>). And so I used charAt().

Comment: @Yggdrasil You asked a question without providing all the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a character wrapper for char primitive type. You can do 
`new Character(char input)`

Answer (score -1):

If you need to get an instance of `java.lang.Character` from `char`, you have two ways:

```
Character c = Character.valueOf('A');
```

Or:

```
Character c = new Character('A');
```

Both ways are equivalent except the first way is more efficient because it uses caching for ASCII characters: `Character.valueOf('A') == Character.valueOf('A')` is always true.

If you need to convert `String` to `Character`, you can use the `charAt` method:

```
Character c = "A".charAt(0);
```

Answer (score -2):

boolean -->Boolean;char --->Character;byte -->Byte;short -->Short;int -->Integer;long -->Long;float -->Float;double -->Double;
So **new Character('A');** should be what you want